# Visio diagram image to Json

Tags: json, image-processing, visio

I was wondering if there is some image-recognition or already existing approach for tackling the following problem.

I have a VISIO generated diagram, which is in practice a custom size image with specific semantic. For example (sorry for the random text):

[image]

Basically, this graph shows various information which has specific semantic:

1. `A`, `d` and `f` are `big_parent`, they are ovals with the yellowish colour;
2. `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are the `children`, they are rects with orangish colour;
3. Gray and Red rects are information added to the `children` or `big_parent`.

I have many other rules, but the concept is: I can perfectly describe each of this characteristics in terms of forms and their colour, with some exception (for example non continuous contours, different contours colours, and so on).

This image should be translated to:

```json
{
    "name": "A",
    "gray_info": "info1",
    "up_card": "0..1",
    "low_card": "1",
    "big_parent": [
        {
            "name": "d",
            "up_card": "0..1",
            "low_card": "1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name" : "a",
                    "up_card": "1..n",
                    "red_info": "info2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "f",
            "up_card": "0..1",
            "low_card": "1..n",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name" : "b",
                    "up_card": "1..n",
                    "red_info": "info3"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "c",
                    "up_card": "0..1",
                    "red_info": "info4"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "d",
                    "up_card": "0..1",
                    "red_info": "info5"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I was wondering how can I tackle a problem like this, or if this is feasible having a limited number of example of images to jsons. How would you approach that? I am worried this may be too hard with some automatic tool (if there exists), and it would be feasible with some AI-based model, but not with limited data.

EDIT: Some clarification:

1. I don't have access to the visio file;
2. There are some rules which I didn't state, as they are not relevant;

Comment: **do not** approach this as a computer vision problem. dig around in the _file_ that is saved by visio (not image file!). office files are just zip files with xml in them.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have access to the visio file.